# Get content of div from HTML string

Tags: jquery

```
var html = '<html><body><header>Header content</header><div id="container">Content I want</div><footer>Footer content</footer></body></html>'
```

Both `$(html).find('#container')` and `$(html).find('div')` seem to return `[]`.

I have tried using `.find()` and `.filter()` to do this, but to no avail.

Comment: Try `$($.parseHTML(html)).filter('#container')`

Comment: I think this would work too: $($.parseHTML(html)).find('#container').html() . I would compare Arun's answer and mine in a jsPerf to see which performs better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when the html is parsed jquery is stripping the `html` and `body` tags.  If you inspect the result, you will see a jquery object with 3 elements, `header`, `div` and `footer`.  As a result, you can do this:

```
$(html).filter('#container')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7AfsW/

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is correct...  fiddle added as proof.

Comment: So, it turns out that I had actually tried this, but got some jQuery object with no context back, and this made me think it was not what I wanted. However, I just tried calling `.html()` on it *did* give me the required content. My bad.